# How to update cart in one function using Gloudemans\Shoppingcart in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, module, cart

I have a problem with the `Gloudemans\Shoppingcart` module, maybe somebody's using it in his shop or he's using it.

For two days now, I've been trying to write a code that will update my card in one `add` function but it doesn't work.

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

```
public function add(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    $duplicates = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) use ($product) {
        return $cartItem->id === $product->id;
    });

    if ($duplicates->isNotEmpty()) {

        MyFlash::success('Item is already in your cart!');

        return redirect()->route('shop.cart.index');
    }

    Cart::add($product->id, $product->name, 1, $product->price)
        ->associate('App\Product');

    return redirect()->route('shop.cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');
}
```

Comment: Hi. What exactly doesn't work? Does we say about this package? https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are missing is the Buyable interface, As they have also mentioned [here](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#models)

"If your model implements the Buyable interface and you used your model to add the item to the cart, it will associate automatically."

You can find the buyable interface in Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Contracts\Buyable;

```
<?php

namespace App\Product;

use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Contracts\Buyable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model implements Buyable
{
   // ...your code...
}
```